# How to add two DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame number 1

**Price  Things**

0   1     pen

1   2     pencil

2   6     apple

I have DataFrame number 2:

**Price   Things**

0   5      pen

1   6      pencil

2   10     cup

I want to join two DataFrames and I'd like to see this DataFrame:

DataFrame number 1 + DatFRame number 2

**Price   Things**

0   6     pen

1   8     pencil

2   6     apple

3   10    cup

How can I do this?

This code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Things': ['pen', 'pencil'], 'Price': [1, 2]})


series = pd.Series([1,2], index=[0,1])

df["Price"] = series
df.loc[2] = [6, "apple"]
print("DataFrame number 1")
print(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Things': ['pen', 'pencil'], 'Price': [1, 2]})
series = pd.Series([5,6], index=[0,1])

df2["Price"] = series

df2.loc[2] = [10, "cup"]

print("DataFrame number 2")
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `concatenate function` to combine two `dataframes` along `axis = 0`, then `group by` column and `sum` them.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=0).groupby('Things').sum().reset_index()
df3
```

Output:

```
    Things  Price
0   apple      6
1     cup     10
2     pen      6
3  pencil      8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge, add, then drop the interim columns:

```
common = pd.merge(
    df,
    df2,
    on='Things',
    how='outer').fillna(0)
common['Price'] = common.Price_x + common.Price_y
common.drop(['Price_x', 'Price_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> common
    Things  Price
0   pen 6.0
1   pencil  8.0
2   apple   6.0
3   cup 10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set *Things* as index on both data frames and then use [`add(..., fill_value=0)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
df.set_index('Things').add(df2.set_index('Things'), fill_value=0).reset_index()

#  Things   Price
#0  apple    6.0
#1    cup   10.0
#2    pen    6.0
#3 pencil    8.0
```